# Size in iPhone app using xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am building an app specifically for my iPhone 5s in portrait mode. I have used both **wCompact hAny** and **wCompact hRegular** but my view is still clipped from sides.
Any suggestions?

Comment: FYI - You aren't allowed to build an app for just one iPhone. Apple will require that you support the iPhone 4s (3.5" screen) in addition to the 4" screens. And you should really support the iPhone 6 and 6+ screens (Apple will make that mandatory at some point too).

Comment: `wCompact hAny` or `wCompact hRegular` is for iPhones layout....this doesn't mean that it is device specific....you need to give constraints...or use freeform size of 5S for layout

Comment: I am not gonna publish this app on app store, this is just for testing some project work using a iPhone 5s for the moment. Also, it makes no sense to make your app available to public for just one phone.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try using storyboards with auto layout by applying layout constraints to the subviews to keep them constrained inside of the view controllers main view. This will, for the most part, ensure that none of your views get clipped.

Here is an auto layout tutorial from Ray Wenderlich. [Adaptive Layout Tutorial: Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial)